# How to show that a set is connected

Tags: general-topology, analysis, connectedness, path-connected

Can someone please explain to me the idea of connectedness and how they relate to these sets? I understand the definition of connectedness, but I am struggling to relate the definition to these examples. I am faced with the following problem:

Show that each of the following sets are connected:

a) The grid $$G = \{x \in \mathbb{R}^2: x = (x_1, x_2) \text{ and at least one } x_i \in \mathbb{Z}\}\text{.}$$

b) The cone $$K = \{x \in \mathbb{R}^{d+1}: x = (s, y) \text{ where } y \in  \mathbb{R}^d \text{ and } |s| = ||y|| \}\text{.}$$

c) Any convex set $C \subseteq R^d$. 
(Recall that a set $C$ is convex iff for each $x, y \in C$ the line segment $\{\lambda x+(1−\lambda)y: \lambda \in [0,1]\} \subseteq C$.

Comment: In many cases, you can show that a set is connected by showing that it is path-connected. For the example $a)$, draw the grid : it is clear that given any two points of the grid, you can construct a path included in the grid, and joining them, isn't it ? So the grid is path-connected and hence connected.

Comment: (To be clear, note that a set can be connected but not path-connected. I am not saying that these two concepts are equivalent, but that path-connectedness implies connectedness)